# knitr not aligning figures to center when image is expanded (.pdf document)

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to increase the size of an image in a .pdf document using `knitr`, but when I try to do this the image shifts to the right and off the page. Here is the syntax I am using:

````
```{r test_image,  echo = FALSE, out.width = '150%', fig.align = 'center'}
 knitr::include_graphics("test_image.png")
```
````

I have also tried inserting `fig.height` and `fig.width` to adjust the height (instead of using `out.width`) but I still get the same thing. I have also tried `fig.align = 'left'` to keep the image on the page but that does not solve the issue either.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior? Is there a way to maintain the image centering when increasing the image size?

[image: This is the image]
[image: This is how it renders]

Comment: In the pdf or html you see this problem?

Comment: I'm trying to knit a .pdf document

Comment: I don't see something strange. Can you add your picture (if it doesn't secret one)? I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: OK I added the image and also a picture of how it renders in .pdf when out.width = "150%". It looks fine when out.width = "100%"

Comment: One moment, I'll try.

Comment: Hm, I see it, interesting.

Comment: You get the same thing?

Comment: Yes, I'll try to do something

Comment: Can you share the images?

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts.

I think, that this problem exists because of "big amount" of whitespace on left and right sides of your picture.

You can trim it manually and add after with `knitr::include_graphics` or do it with latex straightaway:

**Add to your header:**

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
```

**Add your pic**

```
\includegraphics [trim={5cm 0 5cm 0},clip]{Ml6KL.png} 
#you can also customize your width/height 
#\includegraphics [trim={5cm 0 5cm 0},clip, width = XX, height = XX]{Ml6KL.png}
```

**An output:**

[image]

**P.S.** If you can - try to find better versions of first two logos(or scale < 1). As you can see - the quality leaves much to be desired...

Comment: Thanks. It happens with every image I have for this paper, not just this one. I'll mess around with the white space, but I wonder why it would push the image to the right if the white space is equal on all sides of the image?

Comment: @EmmanuelTeitelbaum Honestly, don't know. Maybe - It's a bug(?).